# Excel 2013 32bit and 64bit crashing on form

Tags: microsoft-excel, forms

Excel 2013 32bit and 64bit crashing on user form.
I don't know what's wrong with this form.  Does anyone see any problems?  Is there a change in codes, value, attributes from Excel 2007 to 2013 that I was supposed to change?

This form appears to cause crashes when trying save the Excel file or when opening the form.  If I delete the form, the crashing stops.
There is only a handful of objects like a listbox, form, buttons.

Also note, there is no code for the form...I deleted it all, but still crashes.  It appears to run out of memory.  Some kind of loop error?
Also note, the form was created probably way back in Excel 1999, moved up through the upgrades over the years.  Never recreated from scratch.

[image: Command Button 1]

[image: Command Button 2]

[image: Error Crash Message]

[image: ListBox]

[image: UserForm]

Comment: Information on the crash might help.  Since your asking what is causing the crash itself.

Comment: The link for the images have now been updated to show the crash message.  Also noted below: Exception Code: c0000005, Exception Offset: 00000000000d736d

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to post images.  Can you grant me 10 reputation?

Comment: You can post links to the images.  Somebody with enough reputation will merge your images into your question at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is 2010 or older and it has protection on it, open the file in 2013 and go to File and on the right in the Info pane you'll see Protection. Remove all protection then add it back in. Save and close the workbook. 2013 uses a very complex algorithm in its protection and the workbooks / sheets of versions 2010 and older didn't and this can cause issues.

Other things that were tried along with this answer:

- You could try this. When the file open dialog comes up don't actually double-click the file, but just get it selected in the list.  It may not even show up in the filename section of the dialog at this point.  But now the "Open" button and its drop-down arrow should be available to you. At the bottom is Open and Repair or something like that. I upgraded to 2013 now so can't check.

[image]

- Try disabling plug-ins (ActiveX should be the first you try)
- Start in Safe mode (1. Click Start, point to All Programs, and then point to Microsoft Office. 2. Press and hold the CTRL key, and then click the name of the Microsoft Office program that you want to run.)
- Do your files point to any data sources? Other sheets / workbooks that are no longer where you're pointing?
- Are you able to try loading / saving etc on a different PC? (It could be something on your PC causing the problem and not the actual file. You may have settings that do not allow macros to run for example)
- If your files have an extension of .xlsm or .xlsb these files are Excel versions of a .zip file. Change the extension to .zip and you will be able to see what the file contains. You can also read the .xml files and remove things such as printers.